# How do I find an analytic solution to this recursive function?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I was playing with some recurrence relations, and I ended up with this a long nested function. How can I generalize the following relationship:

$$ f_n = a + \frac{b}{f_{n-1}} $$

---

$$ f_1 = a + \frac{b}{f_0} $$

$$ f_2 = a + \frac{b}{f_1} = a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{f_0}} $$

$$ f_3 = a + \frac{b}{f_2} = a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{f_0}}} $$

$$ f_4 = a + \frac{b}{f_3} = a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{a + \cfrac{b}{f_0}}}} $$

For each iteration, another function gets nested in the denominator. Is there any way to generalize this behavior for an $n^\text{th}$ iteration?

Comment: What do you mean? By definition $f_n = a+\frac{b}{f_{n-1}}$, I believe, that is the generalization. Are you asking how to explicitly (not sure, if it is the right word) express $f_n$ without previous $f_{n-1}$, that is to avoid the recursion?

Comment: Ah, yes. I should have been more specific. Like you said, I want to eliminate the $f_{n-1}$ term in order avoid that behavior.

Comment: there is an explicit formula

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner -- What should I look into? Is there a proper term for this "nesting?"

Comment: the term that produces Mathematica looks very ugly

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Do you see a substitution that could simplify the solution for each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called continued fractions and you can find a formula for nicely "collapsing" them here: [Euler's Continued Fraction Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula)

A pretty result that fits into your constraints is that for $a=b=1$ the fractions converge to the golden ratio.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Very happy to help.  Cheers!